# binding of item of an observablecollection to a class property using slider value as an index

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I am trying to display different shapes defined by a `Point3DCollection` object stored in an `ObservableCollection` using a slider in a WPF3D viewmodel. I am using a library that receives the shapes in a `Point3DCollection` object which is declared as a `DependencyProperty`. By using the `Slider` value as an index I am hoping to dynamically update the shape displayed in the window without doing any extra work.

How can I achieve this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DataContext could have a CurrentIndex (or similar name) property which is two-way bound to the Slider.

The setter of the CurrentIndex property should retrieve the shape indexed by CurrentIndex and set the dependency property value to it (by calling SetValue on the DependencyObject which will in turn update whatever's bound to it).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will post the outcome when I try the idea.